# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools' at Error (native)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium

I am new to *Appium* and I am running a *selenium script* with device connected and while running in terminal i am getting this error:

```
“Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir ‘/Documents/android-sdk-linux/build-tools’ at Error (native)”
```

I am running in *Linux.* Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Likely there is no build-tools folder at that location. Does it exist or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to paste this two lines in .bashrc file
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/rijomon/Documents/android-sdk-linux/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
then you will not get that error

Answer (score 1):

This error is caused when Appium can not find a valid path to the Android SDK in the ANDROID_HOME environment variable

...or when the SDK installation is corrupt.

Rijo Mon's answer is correct for his system but the ANDROID_HOME path will need to be changed to point to the actual location of your installed SDK.

- Install [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools) if you aren't already using it.
- Make sure only one version of Android SDK is installed in Android studio, and make sure Android Studio does not display any errors or warnings about the SDK installation.

  1. Go to Android Studio Preferences  → Appearance and Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK
  2. Uninstall all installed Android SDK versions here by unchecking
     their boxes and clicking Apply
  3. Uninstall any other copies of the Android SDK on your system
  4. In Android Stduio, check only one SDK version and install it by clicking Apply.
  5. Close and re-open Android Studio (you may want to reboot your machine)
  6. Go back into the Android SDK window in Preferences → Appearance and Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK
  7. Confirm that Android Studio does not display any warnings about the installed Android SDK.
- Make sure the ANDROID_HOME environment variable is in your bash_profile and that it points to the location of your installed SDK.  For an SDK installation managed by Android Studio on OSX, this should be ~/Library/Android/sdk

  1. The output of "ls -l ~/Library/Android/sdk" or the ls for your correct path to your SDK should now show a directory listing with the installed SDK files and folders including "build-tools" and "emulator"
  2. Add the following line to ~/.bash_profile (OSX) or ~/.bashrc (Linux)

     - export ANDROID_HOME="${HOME}/Library/Android/sdk" (replace the path with your actual SDK path)
  3. Restart your terminal or source the modified bash profile with "source ~/.bash_profile" or "source ~/.bashrc"